# Stop and start videos within a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've been playing around with this for a day now and have hit a brick wall.

I want to have a `UIScrollView` that shows a series of videos that the user can scroll across. Setting up the `UIScrollView` is fine and each item within it (I'm calling them MenuItems) is a subclass of `UiViewController` that contains and manages all of the setup of the `MPMoviePlayerController` etc.

I discovered however that you can only have one `MPMoviePlayerController` in a window, playing at once.

So, I thought the best way to handle this is to have accessible methods on each MenuItem, `stopVideo` and `startVideo` that I would trigger as each menu item became the "focus" of the `UiScrollView` (I have successfully coded the delegate so that it captures the scroll event and works out which page is in the centre of the scrollview).

The problem is, I can't work out how to access the MenuItem objects in the `UiScrollView`.

I have the following code in the `UIScrollView` delegate to do this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sView {

//establish what page we're on
static NSInteger previousPage = 0;
MenuItem *currentMenuItem;
MenuItem *previousMenuItem;

CGFloat pageWidth = sView.frame.size.width;
float fractionalPage = sView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
if (previousPage != page) {
    //firstly, get the previous page and stop the video
    previousMenuItem = [sView.subviews objectAtIndex:previousPage];
    previousMenuItem = [previousMenuItem nextResponder];
    [previousMenuItem hideVideo];

    //[previousMenuItem release];

    //page has changed, get the new current page and start the video
    currentMenuItem = [sView.subviews objectAtIndex:page];
    currentMenuItem = [currentMenuItem nextResponder];
    [currentMenuItem showVideo];


    //[currentMenuItem release];

    previousPage = page;
}
```

}

The methods `showVideo` and `hideVideo` are called, but I get other errors (for example, I can't seem to initialize an `MPMoviePlayerController` inside the `MenuItem` without an `SIGABRT` error).

I'm thinking my methodology is flawed here or that there is a simpler approach? All help appreciated!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bit late for a response but I got stuck on this as well and managed to bash out a solution so thought I'd include it for anyone else.

I think it has to do with memory allocation for the movie players.

I included this code in my .h file

```
@interface VideoInstructionViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player0;
    MPMoviePlayerController *player1;
    MPMoviePlayerController *player2;    
}
```

and so that the movie players were effectively global and then just included this code in my .m file.

```
player0 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:contentURL];
player1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:contentURL];
player2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:contentURL];
```

The rest of your code was very useful, I think it's a solid methodology, thanks!